# How to mount System Volume using APFS snapshot

Tags: macos, mount, snapshot, apfs

I am not able to mount System Volume (root) using APFS. I only see my Data Volume.

```bsh
$ mkdir /tmp/snapshotbackup_root
$ mount_apfs -s com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-10-29-174444.local / /tmp/snapshotbackup_root
$ df -h /tmp/snapshotbackup_root
Filesystem                                                   Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-10-30-121116.local@/dev/disk1s3  223Gi   97Gi  115Gi    46% 1904164 2340358076    0%   /private/tmp/snapshotbackup_root
```

As you can see, it only mounts `/dev/disk1s3`, I am unable to mount the System Volume which is `/dev/disk1s1`.

```bsh
$ mount_apfs -s com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-10-29-174444.local@/dev/disk1s1 / /tmp/snapshotbackup_root
mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: No such file or directory
```

Time Machine can mount it as seen below

```bsh
$ df -h "/Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/Backups.backupdb/MacBook Pro 840 G3/2019-10-29-174444/OSX"*
Filesystem                                                   Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-10-29-174444.local@/dev/disk1s1  223Gi   10Gi  115Gi     9%  481433 2341780807    0%   /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/Backups.backupdb/MacBook Pro 840 G3/2019-10-29-174444/OSX
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-10-29-174444.local@/dev/disk1s3  223Gi   96Gi  115Gi    46% 1899738 2340362502    0%   /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/Backups.backupdb/MacBook Pro 840 G3/2019-10-29-174444/OSX – data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
mount_apfs -s com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-10-29-174444.local /dev/disk1s1 /tmp/snapshotbackup_root
```

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: The command seems to be expecting the device name `/dev/disk1s1`, not `/`

Comment: Note: I had to use `/dev/disk1s2` instead of `/dev/disk1s1`.  This is likely a semi-recent change.  I got this by running `diskutil list` and looking for the disk identifier on `Macintosh HD - Data`.